# Springboot does not seem to pick up on this endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot

I currently have two files. The first file is simple `Service.java` which contains the following code in the file path `demo/Service.java`

```
package com.clubmgmt.clubmgmtstudentservice;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Service {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Service.class, args);
    }
}
```

My second file `StudentController.java` belongs in the file path `demo/student/StudentController.java` and contains

```
package com.clubmgmt.clubmgmtstudentservice.student;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/test")
public class StudentController {
    @GetMapping("/get") //Root page
    public List<String> getStudents() {
        return List.of("Please", "Work");
        
    }
```

However, accessing `localhost:8080/test/get` seems to still give me a whitelabel error page. I have tried to resolve the issues but everything seems to be in order. When i run the springboot application from `Service.java`, there seems to be no error either. The route shows up under the EndpointMappings of a VSCODE plugin as well.
This is the SpringBoot logs when running the application

```
 D:\01. GitHub\personal-archive\schoolRelated\esd-project\ESDGroup2\club-mgmt-student-service> D: && cd "D:\01. GitHub\personal-archive\schoolRelated\esd-project\ESDGroup2\club-mgmt-student-service" && cmd /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe" @C:\Users\limxu\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_dbr9avx6o54yics09eig13usu.argfile com.clubmgmt.clubmgmtstudentservice.ClubMgmtStudentServiceApplication "

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-03-02T23:26:20.845+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] c.c.c.ClubMgmtStudentServiceApplication  : Starting ClubMgmtStudentServiceApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 20340 (D:\01. GitHub\personal-archive\schoolRelated\esd-project\ESDGroup2\club-mgmt-student-service\target\classes started by limxu in D:\01. GitHub\personal-archive\schoolRelated\esd-project\ESDGroup2\club-mgmt-student-service)
2023-03-02T23:26:20.850+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] c.c.c.ClubMgmtStudentServiceApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-02T23:26:22.490+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-03-02T23:26:22.504+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-02T23:26:22.504+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-02T23:26:22.601+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-02T23:26:22.602+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1648 ms
2023-03-02T23:26:22.772+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [           main] o.s.w.f.ServerHttpObservationFilter      : Filter 'serverHttpObservationFilter' configured for use
2023-03-02T23:26:22.943+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2023-03-02T23:26:23.080+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2023-03-02T23:26:23.116+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2023-03-02T23:26:23.130+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2023-03-02T23:26:23.456+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-03-02T23:26:23.558+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-02T23:26:23.580+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [           main] c.c.c.ClubMgmtStudentServiceApplication  : Started ClubMgmtStudentServiceApplication in 3.389 seconds (process running for 3.867)
2023-03-02T23:26:23.948+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-03-02T23:26:23.949+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-03-02T23:26:23.949+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2023-03-02T23:26:23.950+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2023-03-02T23:26:23.952+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2023-03-02T23:26:23.954+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@5a346d64
2023-03-02T23:26:23.955+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@1aff1d9c   
2023-03-02T23:26:23.956+08:00 DEBUG 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked 
to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-03-02T23:26:23.958+08:00  INFO 20340 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
```

The error I am getting when trying to access `localhost:8080/test/get` is below

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Mar 02 21:34:54 SGT 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Module Structure is as follows

```
src/
|__main/
   |___java/
      |___com/
          |___clubmgmt/
               |__clubmgmtstudentservice/
                  |__Service.java
                  |__student/
                     |__StudentController.java
                     |__Student.java
```

Comment: Please give us the log after reproducing the error page. I also think the @RequestMapping takes a value instead of path as parameter

Comment: @grekier you can use either.

Comment: File path is not really relevant. What *packages* are these things in, and is the controller definitely on the classpath?

Comment: You need to add your log output to your question, and check that `StudentController` is being instantiated.

Comment: Also include your application.properties, maybe it contains the context path set

Comment: Added in the packages, how do I check if StudentController is being instantiated?

Comment: My application.properties is currently empty!

Comment: Can you add your module structure?

Comment: Have added module structure in.

Comment: Please, add `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` to your `application.properties` file and update the trace in your question. I kind of suspect

Comment: Added and updated trace!

Comment: Oops, I didn't finish writing my comment but didn't notice haha. I also wanted to see the trace after you hit your `/test/get` endpoint. This is because, after trying your code on my machine worked first try. The extra bit in application properties should give you more info about how the app handled the request.

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue why it does not work on my side at all. Everything seems to be right inline with what tutorials and past projects show. If I were to use the @RestController, @RequestMapping inside my `Service.java` file, the mapping works. This makes me think this could be something with how SpringBoot does not scan the controller file, but my file directory / setup looks correct too.

Comment: You can list all instantiated beans with localhost:8080/actuator/beans. More here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. TL:DR, one of my parent directories (in this case, my desktop username) had a SPACE in it like `01 Github` which got converted into `01%20Github`. Upon enabling `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG` under `application.properties` I saw the following error

```
[D:\01.%20GitHub\esdproject\studentservice\target\classes\com\clubmgmt\studentservice] for files matching pattern [**/*.class]: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\01.%20GitHub\esdproject\studentservice\target\classes\com\clubmgmt\studentservice
```

This made me check and realise that the space was not being recognized correctly. I move everything to a folder with no spaces and it works now. Not really sure how it worked with my previous projects, could be a newer version of Springboot that parsed the space different or something.

Please avoid spaces they are the devil.

Answer (score 1):

The packages (modules) structure and the files (directories) structure must be the same. You need to move the java files accordingly.

For example:

demo/Service.java move to src/main/java/com/clubmgmt/clubmgmtstudentservice/

As a general rule: avoid modifying the package with just editing the source file. Most IDE have a function "Move Class" doing both - modifying the package and moving the file.

Comment: I believed i made an initial mistake previously. Both files structures should be correct now.  My `@SpringBootApplication` has the package `package com.clubmgmt.clubmgmtstudentservice;` while my Controller has the package `package com.clubmgmt.clubmgmtstudentservice.student;
`

Comment: Similar to this question, I realised I had whitespaces in my file directory that was being converted into `%20` and not back, therefore when Springboot tried to find the paths it was looking in the wrong folder that did not exist.

Answer (score -1):

try to use
@GetMapping(value = {"/api/v1/get-report"})

Regards,

Comment: What is "this format"? I don't understand what you're suggesting. What difference would it make? What's wrong with their approach?

Answer (score -1):

try to use `@RequestMapping("/test")` instead of `@RequestMapping(path="/test")`

Comment: `value`, the default annotation element, is a synonym for `path`.